# Select2 not working when using require validation with HTML

Tags: html, jquery-select2

I have a question. Select2 is not working for me when I try to use required.

```
<form method="POST" action="/example">
  <select class="select2" name="test" required>
      <option>Test</option>
      <option>Test2</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

If I use `required multiple`, then it works but select2 element don't work with the same behavior. I don't need a multiple select.

I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with allowClear = False:

```
$('select').select2({
  placeholder: 'This is my placeholder',
  allowClear: false
});
```

Also you can use "multiple" and set  maximumSelectionLength in 1

```
 $('select').select2({
      placeholder: 'This is my placeholder',
      maximumSelectionLength: 1
      allowClear: false
  });
```

And also you can try adding the required attributte to the element after the init

```
$('#idSelect').select2();

$('#idSelect').attr("required", "required" );
```

Comment: Hi! I tested. First one option didn't worked for me. I have a question for second one. I could be used as a select? Or the data is like an array if I put the limit to one? Thanks!

Comment: I use select2 in a razor view with ajax.beginform an the data is submited like a select. Not sure if in your case you have to handle an array. Just trying.